# Background cairomm

Tags: c++, gtk

Tengo un dibujo donde pinto así::

```
// ******** Drawing the background ********* \\
// Setting the color for the background
cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 1, 1, 1, 1);
// Setting a rectangle
cairo_rectangle (cr, 0, 0, 200, 200);
cairo_stroke_preserve(cr);
cairo_fill(cr);
cairo_save(cr);
```

Cuando pinto de nuevo sobre el fondo de esta manera (solo ejemplo):

```
//Painting the signal
cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 1);
cairo_move_to(cr, 10, 10);
cairo_line_to(cr, 20, 20);
cairo_stroke(cr);
```

El color, en este caso azul, no es azul rgb (0,0,1) debido al fondo blanco. Mi pregunta es: si quiero un fondo blanco pero el color de la línea azul rgb (0,0,1), ¿cómo lo hago?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El color de la línea que pintarías sí sería azul rgb, porque pintas sobreescribiendo el cuadro blanco, igual que cuando pintas en un programa de edición de imágenes tipo *paint* sobre un fondo blanco: el último color, es el que cuenta.

En tu caso, como no has puesto transparencias, tanto al cuadro de fondo `rgba:= (1, 1, 1, 1)` como a la línea a pintar `rgb:= (1, 1, 1) <-> rgba:= (1, 1, 1, 1)` **machacas** el valor original que hubiese. Si hubieses usado un color de rgb con un valor de transparencia distinto de `1`, podrías obtener un valor que no es el azul de máxima intensidad, sino una **interpolación lineal** entre el valor de fondo y el actual.

Para más información, tendrás que buscar en la biografía inglesa lo que significa *Alpha Blending*